# Warum heißt eine Orange auch "Apfelsine" und nicht "Chinaapfel"?

Tags: etymology, regional, compound

Mehr in Norddeutschland und weniger in Süddeutschland kennt man auch das Wort ***"Apfelsine"*** für eine Orange.

Nach üblicher Bildung zusammengesetzter Hauptwörter müsste es aber eigentlich *"Chinaapfel"* heißen, so wie auch im Niederländischen (*[sinaasappel](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sinaasappel)*).

Gibt es eine Erkärung für diese eigentümliche Wortzusammensetzung?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Man nannte die Zitrusfrucht zu Beginn des 18. Jahrhunderts im [Niederdeutschen](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niederdeutsche_Sprache) *Apel de Sina*  (entsprechend zeitgenössischem Französisch *pomme de Sine*, *pomme de Chine*, engl. *China orange*) und *Appelsina* (nach Niederländisch appelsien, das im Niederländischen heute noch landschaftlich statt *sinaasappel* verwendet wird).

Die verhochdeutschte Pluralform lautete *Äpfelsina*. Auch kamen die Namen *Apfel von Sina*, *Chinaapfel* und *Sineser Apfel* vor.

*Sina* war übrigens in der Zeit um 1700 die gängige Bezeichnung für China. Ab Mitte des 18. Jahrhunderts hat sich im nord- und mitteldeutschen Raum die hochdeutsche Form *Apfelsine* durchgesetzt. Im süddeutschen Sprachraum wird heute vorwiegend der Name Orange verwendet.

Das Wort *Orange* hat eine lange, etymologisch interessante Geschichte. Es ist belegt in norddeutschen Formen wie *oranyge appele* (Anfang des 15. Jhs.), *Oranienapffel* (17. Jh.) als Entlehnungen aus dem Mittelniederländischen *appel van arancen*, *aryangen*, *aranie(n)appel*, nl. *oranje(appel)*.

Das [etymologische Wörterbuch nach Pfeifer weiß dazu](http://www.dwds.de/?kompakt=1&qu=orange) Folgendes:

> Dies beruht wie md. südd. Orangenapfel (17. Jh.), Orange (um 1700) auf mfrz. frz. orange, afrz. pome d’orange, das, wohl über aprov. arange, auranja, auf ital. arancio, arancia, altoberital. naranza (mlat. arangia, arancia, arancium) zurückgeht.
>
> Ebenfalls aus dem Ital. entlehnt ist das im Dt. früh bezeugte mhd. arans ‘Apfelsinenbaum’, aranser Plur. ‘Apfelsinen’ (14. Jh.), frühnhd. Arancien Plur. (16. Jh.). Auszugehen ist von auf pers. nāranǧ beruhendem arab. nāranǧ(a) ‘Apfelsine’. Wahrscheinlich werden Apfelsinen seit dem 11. Jh. in Sizilien angebaut, und zwar zunächst eine aus dem Orient stammende rotgoldene, bitter schmeckende Sorte. Sie wird im 16. Jh. von einer aus China stammenden, von den Portugiesen eingeführten süßen Sorte ersetzt, auf die der alte Name übergeht. orange Adj. ‘orangefarben’ (1. Hälfte 17. Jh.), wohl nach gleichbed. mfrz. frz. orange. Orangerie f. ‘Gewächshaus’, älter ‘Bestand an Orangen- und Zitronenbäumen, seltene südliche Pflanzen’, Übernahme im Zusammenhang mit der frz. Gartenkultur um 1700 von frz. orangerie.

Das italienische *arancia* (Orange) stammt laut [Wiktionary](http://it.wiktionary.org/wiki/arancia#Etimologia_.2F_Derivazione) aus dem Arabischen, das wiederum vom persischen *narang* entlehnt wurde, das vermutlich aus dem Sanskritwort *nagarañja* "von Elefanten bevorzugte Frucht" bedeutete. Wer hätte gedacht, das im Wort Orange ein Elefant steckt?

Comment: Da ergibt sich gleich eine Folgefrage: Heißen die Dinger Orange, weil sie orange sind, oder heißt die Farbe so, weil es die Farbe von Orangen ist?

Comment: @fzwo Ja, das ist interessant. Die Frucht war wohl Namesgeber für die Farbe. Wusste auch nicht, dass im Wort ein "Elefant" steckt. :)

Comment: Danke für den tollen Edit :)

Comment: Es heißt aber "narengi" auf Persisch.

Comment: @Gigili vielleicht Altpersisch *narang*? http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/orange "from Arabic نارنج (nāranj), from Persian نارنگ (nārang)"

Comment: Müßte der Elephant dann nicht 'Orang Utan' heißen?

Comment: @splattne: Eigentlich gehören sie drei Kategorien an. (bezüglich der Größe und Geschmack) Die süßen Sorte heißen (orange) "پرتقال(porteqâl)" und alle anderen heißen "نارنج (nāranj)" oder "نارنگی (nārangi)".

Comment: @Gigili Ah, interessant. Danke für die Erläuterung!