# Warum ist das Beschreiben von Gerüchen (ohne Vergleich) so schwer?

Tags: adjective

Wenn ich mit Freunden darüber schreibe, wie eine bestimmte Situation gerochen hat, fällt mir immer wieder auf, dass ich das allerhöchstens mit Vergleichen beschreiben kann ("das roch wie dieses und jenes Essen", "wie faule Eier", ...), aber ich habe für sehr wenige Sachen dort wirklich Begriffe, die den Kern der Sache ohne Vergleich treffen. Das einzige, was ich in etwa treffend beschreiben kann, sind die Intensität und die Umgebung (Wald, Dachboden, Tankstelle, "exotisch", ...), aber beim Letzteren sind es wieder Vergleiche.

Ich lese auch öfter Wiki-Artikel über z.B. Stoffe der Chemie (weil ich aktuell noch Schüler bin und in Chemie oft Hilfe brauche) und dort scheint es mir, als gäbe es ein ähnliches Problem, so werden die meisten Stoffe etwa als "aromatisch" oder "typisch-riechend" usw. beschrieben.

Meine Fragen lauten jetzt so:

- Warum ist es für mich und viele andere (alle?) deutsch-[und englisch]-sprachigen Menschen so schwer, Gerüche ohne Vergleiche zu beschreiben, wenn es doch beim Aussehen von Objekten meist sehr gut geht? "rot" z.B. ist soweit abstrahiert, dass es nicht mehr als Vergleich gilt - auch wenn man natürlich immer an etwas Rotes denkt, sobald man etwas Rotes sieht.
- Gibt es Sprachen, die die passenden Worte für diese Art von Beschreibung haben?
- Wenn ja: Warum hat sich etwas Ähnliches im Deutschen nicht entwickelt?

Comment: Umscheibungen oder Analogien sind oft treffender oder Präziser als Fachbegriffe. Zu deinen Gegendarstellungen: Man kann auch sagen "`Sie trug ein erdbeerfarbenes Kleid.
`". Das kann auch oft präziser sein als nur `rot` zu sagen. Des Weiteren gilt das auch für Geräusche: ich habe schon oft Leute sagen hören, etwas klinge "`elektrisch`".

Comment: Die Fragen sind interessant. Sind aber die ersten zwei, und auch der Titel, nicht OT?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not really addressing the German language. The difficulty you're seeing is not related to language at all. "Red" is a color you can see and it doesn't matter in which language you say it. Sense of smell, feelings, and others are not that easy to define. Why is it difficult to explain a sort of pain. What really is a "dull pain"? It's in your subconscious and you can only compare it with concrete objects, not with abstract words.

Comment: Eine ähnliche Frage wäre vermutlich geeignet für [Linguistics](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 7):

Es sei einmal dahingestellt, inwieweit diese Frage nun tatsächlich spezifisch für Deutsch ist, aber mir fallen spontan eine ganze Reihe von Adjektiven ein, die mit Gerüchen verbunden sind:

#### Etwas riecht ...

- brenzlig
- faulig
- frisch
- blumig
- muffig
- beißend
- stechend
- süßlich
- ...

Mit den Gerüchen ist es ähnlich wie mit anderen Sinneswahrnehmung, bei denen wir zur näheren Präzision Vergleiche hernehmen. Das ist auch bei den Farbbezeichnungen nicht anders:

- *rosa, [orange](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/3154/warum-hei%C3%9Ft-eine-orange-auch-apfelsine-und-nicht-chinaapfel), violett, anthrazit, himmelblau, blutrot, elfenbein, ...*

Answer (score 6):

Sprache entwickelt sich, um die Kommunikation zu ermöglichen. Dabei entstehen Ausdrücke aus Themenbereichen, die Gegenstand der Kommunikation sind. Mediziner kennen tausende Begriffe für Strukturen im menschlichen Körper und Musiker haben eine sehr reichhaltige Sprache, um über Musik zu sprechen. Wenn man aber über etwas nicht spricht, hat man dafür auch keine Worte.

Wenn man ein Inuit in der Polarregion ist, ist Schnee ein sehr wichtiges Gesprächsthema; daher ist Inuktitut eine Sprache, die reich an verschiedenen Ausdrücken für verschiedene Arten von Schnee ist. Hawaiianisch kennt hingegen gar keine Wörter für Schnee, weil der Wunsch, sich in dieser Sprache über Schnee zu unterhalten, kaum vorhanden war.

Gerüche werden in der westlichen Welt als unwichtige Nebensache empfunden. Dazu kommt, dass es so viele verschiedene Gerüche gibt, und die Form „Es riecht nach X“, wobei X ein Ding mit einem charakteristischen Geruch ist, meist völlig ausreicht. (Setze für X ein: Benzin, Rosen, nasser Hund, Rauch, …)

In anderen Kulturen spielen Gerüche eine größere Rolle. Das sind meist Gesellschaften, die viel stärker mit der Natur verbunden sind als wir. In früheren Zeiten war es üblich, diese Völker als „primitiv“ zu bezeichnen; aber vieles, wie z. B. eben der sprachliche Umgang mit Gerüchen, ist sehr viele komplexer als in unserer „hochentwickelten“ westlichen Welt.

Eine 20-Sekunden-Recherche bei Google (Suche nach »gerüche bezeichnen sprachen«) brachte folgende Artikel zutage, die dich interessieren werden:

- [Sprache der Maniq im thailändischen Regenwald](http://www.wissenschaft.de/kultur-gesellschaft/anthropologie/-/journal_content/56/12054/3530591/Buchst%C3%A4blich-dufte-Sprache!/)
- [Sprache der Jahai auf der Malaiisischen Halbinsel](http://www.spektrum.de/news/jahai-sprecher-sind-meister-der-geruchsbeschreibung/1220685)
- [Probleme von Parfümeuren und Werbetextern Bezeichnungen für Gerüche zu finden](http://www.scienzz.de/magazin/art7077.html)

Comment: so in etwa hätte ich es auch geschrieben - eine sehr gute Antwort meiner Meinung nach! Habe auch an das Schnee-Beispiel gedacht. Auch schön in dem Zusammenhang zu nennen ist die Frustration von Grenouille über diese Problematik ('Das Parfum', Patrick Süskind), wenn natürlich auch nur fiktiv

Comment: Grenouilles fiktive Frustration entstand vermutlich aus Süßkinds ganz realer Frustration. Er musste sie nur noch seiner Figur in den Mund legen.

Comment: "Hawaiianisch kennt hingegen gar keine Wörter für Schnee" - das ist [ein Irrtum](http://anthro-ling.blogspot.de/2006/06/language-myth-1-hawaiian-has-no-word.html)

Comment: Daß Inuktitut "reich an verschiedenen Ausdrücken für verschiedene Arten von Schnee ist" ist leider ein [Ammenmärchen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eskimo-W%C3%B6rter_f%C3%BCr_Schnee).