# Kommt die "Mandarine" vom chinesischen Mandarin?

Tags: etymology

Im deutschen Wort [Apfelsine](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/3154/warum-hei%C3%9Ft-eine-orange-auch-apfelsine-und-nicht-chinaapfel) wird ihre Herkunft aus China ("chinesischer Apfel") deutlich. Es liegt also nahe, dass auch unsere [Mandarine](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandarine) ihre Namensgebung aus dem europäischen Wort [Mandarin](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandarin_%28Titel%29) für einen chinesischen Würdenträger, bzw. die chinesische Hochsprache hat.

Gibt es Belege dafür, die über eine ["einleuchtende" Vermutung](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=Mandarine) hinausgehen?

Answer (score 2):

Laut dem [Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=mandarin) stammt der Name in der Tat von den Mandarin, den chinesischen Würdenträgern. Deren Gewand habe die orangene Farbe der Mandarinen gehabt. Außerdem stammen Mandarinen [aus China](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandarin_orange#Production_volume_and_nutrition) bzw. werden (wurden) dort hauptsächlich angebaut. Daher ist die Benennung nach chinesischen Bezeichnungen naheliegend.

Comment: Nun, die Farbe *orange* hat mit Einzug der Orange bereits viel früher den Weg nach Europa gefunden... aber das heißt natürlich nichts.

Comment: @Takkat Orangen sind aber eher gelborange, Mandarinen rotorange, es handelt sich also zumindest um verschiedene Farbtöne.

Comment: Wos??  Mandarinen und Apfelsinen sehen äußerlich für meine Augen völlig gleich aus, rein optisch kann ich die nur anhand der Größe unterscheiden.

Answer (score 1):

Ich zitiere [DWDS.de](http://dwds.de/?qu=mandarine):

> Die Aufeinanderfolge der Entlehnungsvorgänge ist nicht genau bekannt, doch gelangt die Bezeichnung um 1850 wohl aus dem Frz. ins Dt. Zu ihrer Erklärung wird gelegentlich auf ein *Mandara* verwiesen, das Eingeborenenname der für den Südfruchtanbau bes. geeigneten Insel Mauritius sein soll. Einleuchtender ist allerdings der verbreitetere Anschluß an das in nhd. **Mandarin** m. (17. Jh.) vorliegende, von Europäern als Bennennung für einen hohen Würdenträger im kaiserlichen China (chin. guan) gebrauchte Substantiv; in diesem Falle stellt sich der Zusammenhang entweder durch die farbliche Übereinstimmung mit der Tracht der chinesischen Staatsbeamten oder durch die hohe Qualität der Orangenart (botan.-lat. Citrus nobilis) her (also z. B. span. naranja mandarina ‘Mandarinorange’).

Comment: Sorry, hatte den Link in der Frage nicht verfolgt...

Comment: Ich kenne den DWDS-Eintrag (habe ihn in der Frage verlinkt), vielleicht stimmt es ja, aber so ganz 100% schlüssig scheint mir das nicht zur sein. "Mandara" neben "Farbe" neben "hohe Qualität"... Ich würde die Antwort aber stehen lassen, evtl. gibt es ja gar nicht mehr.

Comment: Ich hab die Antwort mal wieder aktiviert, auch wenn es natürlich redundant ist, da Du ja auf den gleichen Eintrag bereits in der Frage verlinkt hattest.

Comment: Danke - kann schon sein, dass niemand etwas anderes findet, dann steht wenigstens der DWDS-Eintrag hier.